# Call function from child frame running program

Tags: javascript, html

Bear with me. It will take a little explaining.

I have a main page that is divided into three <divs> The top <div> has a hyperlink in it. One of the other <divs> (called "menu_div") has an <object> in it which loads a perl script. By default, this is hidden

When the hyperlink is clicked within "header_div", it makes the "menu_div" visible via "parent.document.getlementById('menu_div).style.visibility='visible'" At the same time, it sets a "show_hide" flag to 1

If the user clicks on the hyperlink again, it checks the status of "show_hide", and if set to 1, hides the <div> and sets the flag to 0.

** In effect, each time the user clicks the hyperlink, the box toggles on and off

With the box open, and running the script, all goes well till the final part. I can hide the box again using the visibility statement as above. However, the <header_div> containing the hyperlink is still set with the "show_hide flag at "1", (to say popup window is open)

** So - once the menu.pl script has closed the window, if the hyperlink is clicked again, nothing happens (as it's resetting the "show_hide" flag) But on second click, "menu_div" pops up again. So I need to change "show_hide" to 0 before the program submits the form so it will pop up on FIRST click of hyperlink the next time.

Note: When "menu_div" closes, it sends data to "menu.pl", and the results are displayed within "page_div"

WHAT I'M ASKING IS ....

***How do I get to the show_options function before the program makes the submit call***

That's the explaination: Here is the code

```
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<body> 
<div class="header_div">
<object width="100%" height="30px" id="header" name="header" data="/cgi-bin/header.pl"></object> 
</div>
<div class="page_div" id="page_div">
<object id="page" name="page"
width="100%" height="100%" data="/cgi-bin/page.pl"></object>
</div>
<div class="menu_div" id="menu_div">
<object id="menu"
data="/cgi-bin/menu.pl" width="250px" height="150px"></object>
</div>
</body>
```

+++++

Within "header.pl"

```
<script language="javascript">
var show_hide=0;
function show_options(){
    if (show_hide == 0){
    parent.document.getElementById('menu_div').style.visibility='visible';
    show_hide=1;
    return false;
    }
    if (show_hide == 1){
    parent.document.getElementById('menu_div').style.visibility='hidden';
    show_hide=0;
    return false;
    }
}
</script>
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" bgcolor="#eeaabb">
<table class="header_options">
<tr>
<td width="300px"><font class="head">MY SITE LOGO</font></td>
<td width="100px"><font class="head">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return show_options();">SEARCH</a></font></td>
```

+++++

Within "menu.pl" (Abrreviated script)

```
function checkService(){
var opt1=document.getElementById('service').selectedIndex;
    if (opt1 == 0){
    return false;
    }
\\window.parent.show_options(); \\-- This is where I'm getting probs
\\parent.document.show_options();
\\parent.document.show_hide.value=0;
\\parent.document.getElementById('menu_div').style.visibility='hidden'; \\ -- Will hide menu_div 
document.userChoice.target="page";
document.userChoice.submit();

<select onchange="check_service();">
...
..
.
</select>
```

Comment: instead of `function show_options(){` try `window.show_options = function () {` then it is a global public variable holding a function you should be able to call within your domain; also beware comments in javascript start with `//` or `/**/` and `--` is not allowed within HTML/XML comments

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to provide an answer. As you see below, I have now found a work around, but your answer will help. (What comes after the function (){ ... part?) Re the comment lines. Don't worry; that was just my typing the text into the message box. (Didn't know the /**/ one) For HTML, I use <!-- for comments-->

Answer (score 0):

Seems I was "taking a hammer to crack a walnut" !! All I had to do was - rather than set the "show_hide" flag - was to check the status of the . In otherwords, was if visible or not. (Interestingly, it would not work when checking for the 'hide' attribute, which is why I've used the "not equal to" conditioner)

```
if (parent.document.getElementById('menu_div').style.visibility == "visible"){
parent.document.getElementById('menu_div').style.visibility='hidden';
return false;
}
if (parent.document.getElementById('menu_div').style.visibility != "visible"){
parent.document.getElementById('menu_div').style.visibility='visible';
return false;
}
```

Now it toggles on and off by clicking the hyperlink, hides when I submit form, and opens instantly again when hyperlink is clicked again.